# How to quickly store large records in Extensible Storage Engine

Tags: windows, database, extensible-storage-engine

I'm using Extensible Storage Engine to cache a number of large records - these records tend to be about 2MB in size (each)

Often they will be deleted within a few hours, it's rare that they live for more than this amount of time

I'm in a tight loop of JetBeginTransaction/JetPrepareUpdate/JetSetColums/Update/JetCommitTransaction - each iteration of this loop writes a 2MB record.  the data being written has been preallocated and is in RAM - my producer shouldnt be taking any CPU or disk time

I'm measuring very slow performance,  on the order of 2megabytes a second.

using procmon I see lots and lots of tiny reads and writes (512 bytes, 4096bytes, and lots of writes ~30K). The largest writes I see are 393,216bytes which I believe is the default for JET_paramMaxCoalesceWriteSize.

This feels like a tuning thing,  what can I do to increase performance of large writes?  I'm off almost two orders of magnitude from what this hardware should be capable of delivering.

Comment: you could try adding doing this as a parallel loop... however I am curious why you think the preformance should be better?  what is your total disk read/write throughput.  Seek times could be killing you?  Also when you are doing this, is there a virus scanner running in the background?  GL

Comment: 2megabytes a second is very very slow for large I/Os. with a SATA disk I should be seeing much closer to 120megabytes a second. I suspect a combo of seek times and small writes are killing me - addressing those will prob yield a solution.  Keep in mind I'm making huge writes, for contigious I/Os it doeesnt get much better than 2MB a write. I do not have any scanners, or search engines on, however I do have VSS turned on

Comment: Are you using lazy transactions?